# How to lock unity transform tool to main 3 axes while game object it rotated?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am creating my first prototype game in unity. I have a prefab of a gameobject that has a rotated transform. I am trying to move the object only on 1 axis but the transform tool is rotated with the game object. how do I change this

[image: This is the orientation of the transform tool that I want]

[image: This has the rotation I want, but the transform arrows are also rotated]

Comment: switch from local to global mode .. see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html -> Gizmo handle position toggles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transform Tool Mode examples](https://i.gyazo.com/e81a15336ab474496517b0c049cede25.mp4)

Here are short examples of the ways one can use the transform tool:
The inner selections affect either two or all three axis at the same time, the arrows / rings affect a single axis.

**On the top left of the scene view you have options for Pivot / Center**, this determines whether the object is moved/rotated/snapped based on the objects maximum extents box center or the pivot point of the model / object hierarchy.

**Global / Local changes which coordinate system you want to use when manipulating the transform**, local takes the objects current position / rotation / scale into account, say if your object is rotated 45° along the blue axis and you want to move along the Z(blue) axis, it will move at that 45° angle towards that blue when you are in local mode or if youre in global it will move in world coordinates along the global Z(blue) axis.